# How to Encrypt Home Directory on Windows 10 Home?

Tags: security, windows-10, encryption

I want to encrypt my user's data but not the whole OS. (Secrutiy + Performance)

Is there an option for home directory encryption in Windows 10 Home?

Comment: The only option to encrypt a user's "home directory" in Windows when Bitlocker cannot be used would be to use the built-in encrypted file system solution.  If you cannot use EFS due to the license you have, your only option, is to use a third-party solution which you have also ruled out.

Comment: I only ruled out TrueCrypt Whole System(Which is whole system rather than just user space) or Containers(Which are not transparent)

Comment: Unless, there really isn't anything besides BitLocker/EFS and TrueCrypt for Windows, which would be really sad.

Comment: Windows 10 Home supports device encryption, which is enabled on certain classes of devices ( mainly limited to tablets ), Windows 10 Home does not support EFS and Bitlocker.  [Ronnie Vernon a Microsoft Community  Moderator and MVP said the following "EFS has never been included in the core (Home, Starter, Basic) versions of Windows."](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-files/how-to-enable-efs-encryption-in-windows-8/b90660a8-8758-4ec3-9d20-db6dea2f6dc6) which is indeed the case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to encrypt home folder on windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/62449/is-it-possible-to-encrypt-home-folder-on-windows-7)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, not quite; I went over the answers and non worked; either unavailable in Win10Home or not what was required.(Home Directory Encryption)

Comment: @Ramhound I think your comments would be a valid answer and if there is indeed no other option than to get a Win10 Pro license so be it.

Comment: I marked it as a possible dupe because (IMO) it's asking the same question, and getting the same answers, because of the same issues ("Home" version of OS, for one).  Anyhow, takes more than my vote to close this. :)

Comment: Yeah, for sure, one vote less would be great though. I tried to search for a solution before posting and I even linked to one of the answers of the "dupe" from the begining specifically noting that it didn't work.

Comment: @FabiánH.jr. - My official answer to this question, would be to go look at the duplicate question, since the existing answers to that the duplicate question is exactly what I would provide if this was a unique question.  One of the solutions, literally suggests an alternative to the NTFS EFS solution, which of course be the Windows version of [EncFS](http://members.ferrara.linux.it/freddy77/encfs.html)

Comment: "Not a single answer in Is it possible to encrypt home folder on windows 7? works for Windows 10 Home".  Those answers (mostly) don't work for Windows 7 Home either.  Practically all answers there would work equally well for Windows 10 Home as they do for Windows 7 Home.  which (other) ones did you actually try?  Why didn't they work?  Anyhow, I'm done bugging you.. :)

Answer (score 2):

File / Device encryption requires device support of a TPM 2.0 chipset and InstantGo. A 3rd party app would be required for file encryption in your situation as well since EFS is not supported in Windows 10 Home.

Further details can be found via Microsoft's Windows 10 Specifications: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications

Answer (score 1):

The only option to encrypt a Home Directory in Windows 10 is EFS, however it is only available in Windows 10 Pro [[1](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-files/how-to-enable-efs-encryption-in-windows-8/b90660a8-8758-4ec3-9d20-db6dea2f6dc6)]

Another alternative is to use BitLocker/Device Encryption if the computer has a TPM (Which is required in Windows 10 and [can be overriden](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/bitlocker-in-windows-10-without-tpm/f79add65-17c2-4a5d-92d6-e4d2a387119f))